# Data updation and deletion error

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and many text fields to add data into the database. When i add a new data, it gets updated in the database and in the data grid.But when i delete the data, it gets deleted only from the database. It doesn't get updated in the data grid.

When i try to update the data, it updates only one record at a time.when i try for another record it gives me a error `"The variable name '@date' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."` I have to close and reopen the form to update a new record.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Form
Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server = DEL-PC; Database=Shj; Trusted_Connection=yes;")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter


Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11)

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles newbtn.Click


If RegNoTextBox.Text <> "" Then
cmd.Connection = con
con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "insert into WaterProofing(Date,RegNo) values ('" & DateDateTimePicker.Value & "','" & RegNoTextBox.Text & "')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Call showdata()
con.Close()

Else
MessageBox.Show("Please enter registration number")
End If
End Sub

//updation
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles editbtn.Click

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateDateTimePicker.Value)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regno", RegNoTextBox.Text)
cmd.Connection = con
con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "update WaterProofing  set RegNo= @regno where date=@date"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Call showdata()
con.Close()
MessageBox.Show("Details Updated!")
End Sub


Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles deletebtn.Click
cmd.Connection = con
con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "delete from WaterProofing where date='" & DateDateTimePicker.Value & "'"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Call showdata()
con.Close()
MessageBox.Show("Details Deleted!")
End Sub

Sub showdata()

SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11, "WaterProofing")

With DataGridView
.Update()
End With

End Sub
End Class
```

Please help me in deletion and updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding parameters before declaring `CommandText` at `Button2_Click`

Try it in this way:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles editbtn.Click

Try

    Dim command As New SqlCommand

    con.Open()
    command.Connection = con

    command.CommandText = "update WaterProofing  set RegNo= @regno where date=@date"
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateDateTimePicker.Value)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regno", RegNoTextBox.Text)

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Call showdata()

    MessageBox.Show("Details Updated!")

Catch ex as Exception
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)  
End try

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Basically you have to do the same thing when you load the `DataGridView` for the first time in order to refresh the `DataGridView` with the current data from database after deleting or updating records, so your `ShowData` Sub might look something like this

```
Private Sub ShowData()

Dim Connection As SqlConnection
Connection = New SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")

Try

    Connection.Open()
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Table"

    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Connection)

    Adapter.Fill(DS)

    DataGridView.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
    DataGridView.Refresh()

Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox(ex.Message)

Finally

    Connection.Close()

End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a Lot!!!the update did work for me as u mentioned!!!! but my delete option is still making an issue. It gets deleted from the database but the change doesnot appear on the data grid. i have to close and open my form to see it. i made changes to the code by adding a try catch block as you mentioned for the update.

Comment: Yep, because at `showdata()` you are refilling the `DataGridView` with the old DataSet which contains the same records as before. You will need to update the DataSet from db and then populate the DataGridview with the updated DataSet

Comment: Sub showdata_delete()
        SqlDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet11, "WaterProofing")
        SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11, "WaterProofing")
    
        With DataGridView1
    .DataSource = DataSet11.DefaultViewManager


        End With   -----  this is a new show data i gave for delete. but this deletes and empties the entire data grid. Thank you so much for your patience and helping me. I am really new to vb and is working out on it.

Comment: i tried editing my codes similar to the way you showed.but still the issue exists.please see the code below i have pasted.

Comment: Why are you not using the code I have pasted? I tried it and it is working fine. I just did a change moving the `con.Close()` from the `Finally` block to above the `Showdata()` call.  Whenever a record is deleted, the database is updated and the call to `ShowData()` causes the data in the `DataGridView` are updated.

Comment: i used the same code u just gave.but again only one data can be deleted at a time. When i try to delete another, it shows details deleted but it doesn't get deleted from data grid and database.

Comment: Probably you are doing something wrong. Did you move the `con.close` from `Finally` block to above `ShowData()` call?

Comment: yes i did.have posted my code below..thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: I tried your below code. It is working fine for me when deleting one record. You mean that you want to select and delete more than one row at a time?

Comment: yess...it only deletes one row at a time..if i want to delete another row, i have to close and open the form.

Comment: not more than one row at a time...you select one row in the datagrid click delete.it goes. next i select another row and click delete it doesn't..hope you are able to understand my problem.

Comment: Yep. I understand but i cannot reproduce your problem. It is working fine for me whenever `Button2` is clicked without closing the form

Comment: It makes no sense. It should work for you as well. I think your problem could be that you are deleting records which `date` fields  matches with the date contained at `DateDateTimePicker` and the second record you want to delete does not match with that criteria.

Comment: yes i got the mistake now.when i click the delete button first, it deletes my row from the datagrid and database.but the field is not removed from my textbox. it remains there. and when i try to click on another row on the datagrid, the textbox fields doesnot change accordingly. do you have a suggestion on how it can be removed from there too?

Comment: Then you can do a trick. Replace your `ShowData()` call by this two lines `DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index)`                   `DataGridView.Refresh()`. This way you're removing the line instead loading the `DatagridView` from database again.

Comment: wowww..it workled.that was awesome!!!thanks a lottttt!!!you did help me a lott!!!!

Comment: Congrats!! Glad to help :-) Don't forget to upvote the answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles deletebtn.Click
        Try

```
        Dim command As New SqlCommand

        con.Open()
        command.Connection = con
        command.CommandText = "delete from WaterProofing where date='" & DateDateTimePicker.Value & "'"
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        Call ShowData_Delete()

        MessageBox.Show("Details Deleted!")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally

    End Try
End Sub
```

Private Sub ShowData_Delete()
        Dim Connection As SqlConnection

```
    Try


        Connection = New SqlConnection("Server = DEL-PC; Database=Shj; Trusted_Connection=yes;")
        Connection.Open()
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * from WaterProofing"

        Dim DS As New DataSet
        Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Connection)

        Adapter.Fill(DS)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
        DataGridView1.Refresh()


    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        Connection.Close()


    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: i am getting a warning Warning 1 Variable 'Connection' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. this is for the connection in sub showdelete.

Comment: i dint get where you edited for removing the warning.

Comment: Just moving `Connection = New SqlConnection("YourConnectionString")` above the `Try` block